# Only one AJAX request at a time?

Tags: jquery

I would like to make sure there is only one AJAX request going on (for a user) at a time. This is what I tried:

```
var ajaxFinished = 1;

$('#selector').keyup(function() {

    if (ajaxFinished == 1) {

        ajaxFinished = 0;

        $.get('test.php', { par : "par" }, function(data) {

            // do stuff with data
            ajaxFinished = 1;

        });
    }

});
```

But the problem is the AJAX request gets executed only once now even though I activate the event multiple times.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think Corey has it nailed. Another possibility: Could it be that the code block you quote is inside another function we don't see? Then it *could* be that ajaxFinished is out of scope - correct me if I'm wrong, my knowledge of JS scoping and anonymous functions is not perfect. In that case, you would have to remove the "var" or declare it in the body.

Comment: Yeah, that was it, it was inside an object method, so I had to use this keyword.

Answer (score 3):

Could it be that when you $.get an error is occurring and ajaxFinished is never being reset to 1?

You may want to use $.ajax rather than $.get.  $.ajax will let you catch success and error events.

Answer (score 2):

I guess ajaxFinished should be a global variable. Remove the var keyword. Try:

```
ajaxFinished = 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

if i were coding that function i would split it up and call a timeout

```
var autocomplete_timeout;

$('#selector').keyup(function() {

    if(autocomplete)
       clearTimeout(autocomplete_timeout);
    autocomplete_timeout = setTimeout(300, "autocomplete('"+ this.val() +"');");
});

function autocomplete(param1, param2){
        $.get('test.php', { par : "par" }, function(data) {

            // do stuff with data
            ajaxFinished = 1;

        });
}
```

Something along those lines to buffer the ajax call until 300ms after the user has stopped typing